# How to fix node module live-server to use require('open') instead of require('opn')

Tags: node.js, angular

I was trying to deploy to my AWS environment and I am getting this error under `nodejs.log`

```
/var/app/current/node_modules/opn/index.js:11
const wslToWindowsPath = async path => {
                               ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/live-server/index.js:11:9)

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.14.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angularspree@0.0.1 start: `cd dist && ../node_modules/live-server/live-server.js --port=8081 --host=localhost --entry-file=/index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! Failed at the angularspree@0.0.1 start script 'cd dist && ../node_modules/live-server/live-server.js --port=8081 --host=localhost >--entry-file=/index.html'.
```

I have tried redeploying but the issue still happens.

AWS support suggest reverting to nodejs v6.14.3 but this is no longer available

as for the index.js mentioned, here is the portion of the code and the line where the error is said to be:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    serveIndex = require('serve-index'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    WebSocket = require('faye-websocket'),
    path = require('path'),
    url = require('url'),
    http = require('http'),
    send = require('send'),
    open = require('opn'),<<<< line 9
    es = require("event-stream"),
    os = require('os'),
    chokidar = require('chokidar');
```

OPN is already deprecated. So I install OPEN. But the open = require('opn') is not getting updated.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is because opn (now open) introduced some new features present only in Node 8.3.0 and newer versions... Using newer Node resolves this issue.

Source: https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/305

Answer (score 1):

Change your node version to 8.3 or higher. You can use *n* to do that

```
npm install -g n
n 8.3.0
npm install live-server
```

live server should be installed now. To confirm run the command below to get the installed version number

```
live-server -v
```