# vue cli version is not showing

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Am trying to run vue.js app for that I have installed vue cli by folliwng the official website("https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html"). When i execute any vue commands getting below error, I even cant able to check it's version. Is there anything i missied here?

Step1:- npm install -g @vue/cli
Sep2:- vue --version

The npm version is "6.2.0" and nodejs version is "v6.14.3".

```html
andy@ip-172-16-198-195:~/vue/progressive-weather-app$ vue --version
/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/open/index.js:16
const wslToWindowsPath = async path => {
                               ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/openBrowser.js:9:14)
```

Comment: Maybe you should update you node version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532439/how-to-fix-node-module-live-server-to-use-requireopen-instead-of-requireop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Vue CLI requires Node.js version 8.9 or above (8.11.0+ recommended).

You should update your nodejs version